# Need Duplicates in Select Stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to combine data from two columns. In this process I need duplicates which exist in the table.

The Tables are:

[image: Tables]

Here is the Query which I am using for the combination.

[image: Query]
Finally the result which I get.

[image: Result]

In the result you can see that one GRN_No among 1 & 2 is deleted. I don't want the duplicates to be deleted.
So with duplicates the result should be.

```
bags - 10.00, bags - 10.00, bubbles - 50.00
```

Comment: Edit your question and put your question *as text* in the question.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help fix your code, or test agai at your data, when it's an image I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the group by was collapsing the multiple occurrences of bags.  See code below: First code to generate your tables then the solution.

```
DROP TABLE GRNItems 
CREATE TABLE GRNItems (
GRN_No int,
Item_No int,
Item varchar(25),
Meters decimal(10,2)
)
DROP TABLE GRN 
CREATE TABLE GRN (
GRN_No int,
[SID] int
)

INSERT INTO GRNItems 
VALUES 
( 1,1,'bags', 10.00)
 ,( 2,1,'bags', 10.00)
 ,( 3,1,'bubble', 50.00)
  ,( 4,1,'lawn', 10.00)

  INSERT INTO GRN
VALUES 
( 1,4)
 ,( 2,4)
 ,( 3,4)
  ,( 4,2)

select STUFF(
(select ', ' + CONVERT(Varchar(10), GRNItems.Item)+ ' - ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(900), GRNItems.Meters) 
--INTO #temp
From GRN INNER JOIN
GRNItems ON GRN.GRN_No = GRNItems.GRN_No
WHERE GRN.SID = 4

for xml path('') 
),1,2, '') as [Items - Qty]
```

Result: bags - 10.00, bags - 10.00, bubble - 50.00